# Is it possible to implement repo based hooks in Gitolite?

Tags: git, gitolite

I want to implements repo based hooks in gitolite.

Is it Possible ?

I am using gitolite 3 (g3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Gitolite 3.6+, it is possible with "[repo-specific hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#v3.6-variation-repo-specific-hooks)":

> - add this line in the `rc` file, within the `%RC` block, if it's not already present, or uncomment it if it's already present and commented out:

```
LOCAL_CODE => "$rc{GL_ADMIN_BASE}/local",
```

> - uncomment the '`repo-specific-hooks`' line in the `rc` file or add it to the `ENABLE` list if it doesn't exist.
> - If your `rc` file does not have an `ENABLE` list, you need to add this to the `POST_COMPILE` and the `POST_CREATE` lists. [Click here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#addtrig) for more on all this.
> - put your hooks into your `gitolite-admin` clone, as follows:

```
# on your workstation
cd /path/to/your/gitolite-admin-clone
mkdir -p local/hooks/repo-specific
```

> - Now add your hooks to that directory, but instead of using the git "standard" names (`pre-receive`, `post-receive`, `post-update`), you use descriptive names (e.g. "`deploy`", "`RSS-post`", etc).
> - add them to the repos you want them to be active in, in your conf file. For example:

```
repo foo
    option hook.post-update     =   jenkins
repo bar @baz
    option hook.post-update     =   deploy RSS-post
```

> - add, commit, and push the admin repo.

Comment: How how to Update Gitolite?

Comment: @AnilYadav If you have installed Gitolite from a clone of https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/, then http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#upgrading: 1/ Update your clone of the gitolite source.
2/  Repeat the install command you used earlier (make sure you use the same arguments as before). 3/ Run gitolite setup.

Comment: The Problem is the gitolite setup is done by another guy 2 years before, and the problem is i dont have any documentation for that. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What exact version of Gitolite are you using?

Comment: It  gitolite3 WORKING_CONFIGURARION-0-g772bc88 on git 1.7.1

Comment: This should be part of the official documentation.