# How to implement post commit hook in Gitolite?

Tags: git, gitolite

I want to implement post commit hook for one repo. I know it is possible with repo based hooks. Can any one provide code for Email Notification hook for every commit to respective Dev Team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `post-commit` hook is a [client-side hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks).
Gitolite is an ACL (Access Control Layer) on the *server* side, which manages access to [*bare* repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687327/6309) (where there is no "`git commit`" done, since there is no working tree).

You can [add hooks per repo in Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29541983/6309) (as seen in your previous question), but not a "`post-commit`" one.

You can have a [VREF](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html) (a chained `post-update` hook) which would make any operation you want when receiving commits (like [those examples there](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/master/src/VREF)).
But again, that is on the server side.

You have some example of such `post-update` or `post-receive` hooks in "[Git hook to send email notification on repo changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552360/6309)".